# Mercurial diff subset of files, by file content

Tags: mercurial, diff

I want to do a visual diff of all files in my working copy which contain a given string - say "TODO" or "REL 1.00.01"

The diff is against another revision (specifically the head of another branch).

My platform is Windows, and I think there may be a solution by piping the results from 'hg grep' or 'findstr' into 'hg diffmerge', but can't get my head around the syntax...

How can I do this "Diff of the subset of files containing string X"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that using [filesets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets). I'm using kdiff3 for graphical diff, but I'd imagine diffmerge will do the same:

```
hg kdiff -r<OTHER_HEAD> -r. "set:grep('TODO')"
```

The fileset (`set:grep('TODO')`) selects files in the *second* specified revision containing the given string, then that set of files is compared as normal between the first and second revisions.

[Revsets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) also have a `grep` function, but it doesn't look as though it searches file contents, only changeset metadata.

Comment: Perfect - thank you shambulator :)  It seems that the fileset searches the second revision rather than the working directory.  (Evident by swapping the two revisions in the command in your answer.)  But this is fine, it only removes the choice about which revision will appear on right/left of diff..

Comment: @piedmont: You're right about where the files are selected from. Of course, it makes sense that diff has to choose one of the revisions you specify to look for the files; my original emphasis on working directory was mistakenly based on my previous uses of filesets :) Answer amended.